# Why Kafka consumer freeze?

Tags: apache-kafka

My Kafka consumer freeze after I count the messages in the topic

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='127.0.0.1:9092')
for _ in range(100):
    producer.send('foobar', b'some_message_bytes')
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer('foobar')
for msg in consumer:
    print (1)
```

It won't print anything.

I can successfully print out what topics we have

```
consumer.topics()
{u'clickstream', u'foobar', u'wiki'}
```

Comment: try print(msg) in your Consumer for loop. Also you are sending to the Topic 'foobar' and reading from 'wiki'.

Comment: That also freezes

Comment: Also, consumer = KafkaConsumer('foobar'). Unless the topic Wiki has messages on it of course?

Answer (score 2):

By default, kafka python (and most kafka client) start from last offset, ie will only read new mesages.
In your case, either first start consumer, then producer, either read from beginning

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer('foobar', auto_offset_reset ='earliest')
```